# Highlighting navbar items on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight each navigation bar item according to current section on scroll, but javascript returns me an error such as `Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined`. Here are my codes:

Js:

```
$(function(){
    let aboutOffsetTop = $('#about-section').offset().top;
    let termsOffsetTop = $('#terms-section').offset().top;
    let attendantsOffsetTop = $('#attendants-section').offset().top;
    let askedOffsetTop = $('#most-asked-section').offset().top;
    let contactOffsetTop = $('#contact-section').offset().top;

    $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        let scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop;
        let activeNav;

        if(scrollTop < aboutOffsetTop){
            activeNav = $('.right-nav li:nth-child(1) a');
        }
        else if(scrollTop < termsOffsetTop){
            activeNav = $('.right-nav li:nth-child(2) a');
        }
        else if(scrollTop < attendantsOffsetTop){
            activeNav = $('.right-nav li:nth-child(3) a');
        }
        else if(scrollTop < askedOffsetTop){
            activeNav = $('.right-nav li:nth-child(4) a');
        }
        else if(scrollTop < contactOffsetTop){
            activeNav = $('.right-nav li:nth-child(5) a');
        }

        activeNav.addClass('active-nav');
        $('.right-nav li a').not(activeNav).removeClass('active-nav');
    });
});
```

Comment: try adding a default active nav and while you scroll try and see if your conditions are valid, like say `consol.log` in each `if else` condition and check if they are becoming true